# Ability to pass some extra data to action serverless function?

Tags: hasura

I'm struggling to figure out best approach to following use case:

I am working on a game where user can perform a mutation `equipItem`. This mutation takes in one input which is `itemId`. I then set up custom action in hasura to resolve it through a serverless function. My current issue is that within that serverless function I need to perform calculations on user stats and update them accordingly to item they equiped, to do so I need to query my hasura api in order to get full character data.

This results in extra execution time, hence I wanted to ask if there is a better method? Ideally something where I can query my data from hasura server prior to executing this action, so I can send it and all that my serverless function has to do then is just modify it and return it back.

This should happen at insertion time, so events wont work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to run a query before calling an action is an open issue and something we're thinking about adding to the roadmap.
https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4268

Currently, your idea of making a query in your action to load the character data sounds like the right thing to do. You shouldn't have to worry about to much latency here, the Hasura response to your serverless function should be fairly fast (especially if you're running in the same region).

(Note: I'm from the Hasura team)